# Heroku Deployment Fails with "App crashed" and H10 Error in ChainLit Python App

Tags: python, heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, procfile

**Problem:**

I am encountering an issue during the deployment of my ChainLit Python application on Heroku using Bitbucket Pipelines. While the build and deployment processes seem to run successfully, the application fails to start on Heroku. The latest error messages are as follows:

**Latest Error Logs on Heroku:**

```
2023-12-14T13:21:26.893940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=orchestra-0c5d9997a21d.herokuapp.com request_id=004c96f8-f7b7-4a05-bb99-b16207adc65f fwd="39.51.161.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-12-14T13:21:27.099092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=orchestra-0c5d9997a21d.herokuapp.com request_id=606b1181-07b1-45e7-9672-5fdd8969edae fwd="39.51.161.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Description:**

The application fails to start on Heroku, resulting in an H10 error ("App crashed"). These errors are triggered during attempts to access specific paths, such as `/robots.txt` and `/favicon.ico`.

**Bitbucket Pipelines Configuration:**

```yaml
image: python:3.12-bullseye

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - echo "Building the app"
            - pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
            - pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_KEY=$AZURE_OPENAI_KEY
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT=https://$AZURE_OAI_RESOURCE_NAME.azure.com/
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_VERSION=2023-09-15-preview
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT=$AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT
            - export AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL=gpt-3.5-turbo
            - git archive --format=tar.gz master -o my-app.tar.gz
          artifacts:
            - my-app.tar.gz

      - step:
          name: Deploy to production
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - pip
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:2.3.0
              variables:
                HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
                HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: my-app.tar.gz
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: chainlit run genai.py
```

**requirements.txt:**

```
python-dotenv
langchain
openai
termcolor
chainlit
```

**Error Details:**

The recent errors are related to the app crashing upon receiving requests for `/robots.txt` and `/favicon.ico`. The H10 error code indicates a generic "App crashed" message.

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

I have already tried the following steps:

- Verified the `requirements.txt` file includes all necessary dependencies.
- Checked the `Procfile` to confirm it is correctly configured to run the app.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving this new H10 error during the Heroku deployment.

I appreciate any insights or guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this deployment issue.